# Swift - Implement global activity indicator

Tags: swift, activity-indicator

I'm currently attempting to make a global activity indicator in swift, which is called whenever a fetch to the api is made. The idea is that the activity indicator will appear in the top left of a navigation bar (navigation view controller's child), and is available on every app page.

*Can't show example image due to new account / low rep*

I have the activity indicator displaying correctly, I'm just not sure on how to make it available from any page on the app - i've considered an extension, but am not sure on what the best way to approach it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Activity Indicator Code:**

```
let activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.White)
var activityItem = UIBarButtonItem()

func navBarActivity() {
    // Call navBarActivity() to start activity indicator
    // Use navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil to stop activity indicator
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    activityIndicator.hidden = false

    self.activityItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: activityIndicator)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = activityItem
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend extension like this.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func displayNavBarActivity() {
        let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .White)
        indicator.startAnimating()
        let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: indicator)

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item
    }

    func dismissNavBarActivity() {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    }
}
```

Call `self.displayNavBarActivity()` before api call, and call `self.dismissNavBarActivity()` after api call done.

However, I want you to check `networkActivityIndicatorVisible` of `UIApplication`. Consider using this option.

> Specify YES if the app should show network activity and NO if it should not. The default value is NO. A spinning indicator in the status bar shows network activity. The app may explicitly hide or show this indicator.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/networkActivityIndicatorVisible